# creating dynamic 2d array that automatically adjusts based on list in c# wpf

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Suppose I have a list of objects of a C# class. I wish to have a 2d array (or list of lists, or something else that can do the same) that can hold information of the relations between all objects in the list. The class could look like this:

```
public class SimplePoint
{
    public string strName{ get; set; }
};

public class SimpleRoute
{
    public int iDistance{ get; set; }
};

public class Place
{
    public ObservableCollection<SimplePoint> points;

    // Below array should dynamically increase/decrease size 
    // depending on length of list of points
    // The array should store 2 values for each possible set of points:
    // distance from x to y, and distance from y to x
    public SimpleRoute[, ] routes;
};
```

The 2d array/table should have one row and one column for every element in the list. When an element is added to the list, the 2d array should grow in two directions, and when an element is deleted, the table/array should shrink in two directions.

The two dimensional array as declared in the above code will obviously not work for this. Rather, I am wondering if the 'SimpleRoute' class could somehow abserve the ObservableCollection 'points', and internally maintain the table of distance data.

Later I wish to also be able to store the data from the 2d array/table - or from the class behind/around it - in an XML (through serialization) and be able to load it again (through deserialization). The relation to the list of 'SimplePoints' should be maintained.
Lastly, the data (ie. the distances) in the automatically adjusting table should editable by the user. I will create the GUI using WPF.

I am wondering what is the best approach for this in C#/.NET, but find it hard to think of something elegant. Searching hasen't yielded a lot of results, though I may be looking in the wrong place.

Maybe there is some easy solution? I am relatively newto .NET programming.

Comment: You could improve on your question a lot if you were more specific about your needs, like stating the type of data you are mapping and to what you are mapping it too. "Object" does mean pretty much everything.

Comment: Thank you @JoãoMiguelBrandão for your answer and recommendation. I edited the question, so hopefully it becomes more clear what I am searching for.

Comment: Maybe you want a Dictionary<int,Dictionary<SimplePoint,SimplePoint>> inside each SimpleRoute?

Comment: I can give you a sample if you confirm that that sounds like what you want.

Comment: Do you think that would allow a dynamic table of distances between all 'points'? Best would be if after adding or removing a point, the table af distances automatically adjusts.

Comment: Oh, I think I understand better what you want now. You can't have that happening automatically, you need to Extend an existing Dictionary / List class and modify the Add / Remove methods. Why would you keep a table with this? Isn't better to calculate it only for the relevant points you'll work with in execution?

Comment: I need to be able to edit all relations. Even if most will remain 0 or empty, I still need to be able to edit them. This is why, after modying the source list, I wish to automatically expand or shrink the distance matrix, and display that matrix in something like a DataGrid with wpf. I guess with saving the distance data, I could only save what is relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you're asking for information on quite a big domain of .net / general OOP practices, so it's really hard to provide a decent answer without a bit of context, but I'll try to give you some pointers.

I'm assuming you have two classes, say Group and Person, with the following simple definitions:

```
class Group
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Persons = new List<Person>();
}
class Person
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
    public Person(string name, int age)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

You have created an object Group with an 1:N relationship to the object Person.
You can test this method with the following test function:

```
public static void test()
{
    Group group =new Group();
    group.name= "Friends";

    Person p = new Person("John",30);
    Person p2 = new Person("Rute",25);
    Person p3= new Person("Richard",17);

    group.Persons.Add(p);
    group.Persons.Add(p2);
    group.Persons.Add(p3);

    foreach(Person person in group.Persons)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} is {1} years old. He is in group {2}.",person.name,person.age,group.name);
    }
}
```

Is this what you intended? If you want to create a different type of relationship (N:N, N:1), I can modify my code to help you with that too.